# ASP.Net MVC 5 -Attempt by security transparent method 'WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider.ValidateUser to access security method failed

Tags: validation, authentication, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, simplemembership

I am using Simplemembership in my asp.net web api project. When i try to validate the user using the below code, i get the error(Error 1)

```
 if (!Membership.ValidateUser(username, password))
       {
         throw new ValidationException("Username or pwassword is incorrect.");
       }
```

Error 1:

> Attempt by security transparent method
>   'WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider.
>   ValidateUser(System.String, System.String)' to access security
>   critical method 
>   'System.Web.WebPages.StringExtensions.IsEmpty(System.String)' failed.

Earlier i got a similar error(Error 2) which i resolved by installing these packages:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebHelpers

Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.Data
```

Error 2:

> Attempt by security transparent method
>   'WebMatrix.WebData.PreApplicationStartCode.OnConnectionOpened(
>   System.Object, WebMatrix.Data.ConnectionEventArgs)' to access security
>   critical method 'System.Web.WebPages.
>   HttpContextExtensions.RegisterForDispose(System.Web.HttpContextBase,
>   System.IDisposable)' failed.

I did clean the solution and tried, still getting the same error,
Do i need to install any more packages or does even the simplemembership work in web api?

Answer (score 0):

The current fix for me was by upgrading to .Net 4.5.3. I figured this out of frustration. This issue doesnt just affect MVC 5 but core Webmatrix projects as well after upgrading to webpages 3.2.3. I think it is a framework issue that will be fixed with the new Microsoft Identity. The current fix for me is below:
*Note: Please use the property pages wizard in visual studio to change your target framework to .Net Framework 4.5.3. It will update your web.config*

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.3">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

Step 1: Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebHelpers

Step 2: Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.Data

Step 3: [Optional] Install-Package Owin

Step 4: Change targetFramework to .Net 4.5.3 via Property pages dialog box

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Ifeanyi- I didn't upgrade to .Net 4.5,but i rather upgraded the webmatrix project to 3.0.